# Html/Css my html doesn't work with my header

Tags: html, css

I have 2 files. The first is my content and the second is my header (on the left).

When i use my new header my html disappears.

There is my html/css header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans&display=swap');

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .sidebar{
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #080808;
  position: fixed;
}

.wrapper .sidebar h2{
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li{
  padding: 28px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2a00fa;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
}    

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a{
  color: #bdb8d7;
  display: block;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a .fas{
  width: 25px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover{
  background-color: #594f8d;
}
    
.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover a{
  color: #fff;
}
 


.wrapper .main_content{
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 200px;
}



    </style>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Side Navigation Bar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b99e675b6e.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
    <img src="https://www.cfnews.net/var/cfnews/storage/images/mediatheque/hd/standard-hd/logos/equitim-art-logo-2019/9643799-1-fre-FR/Equitim-ART-logo-2019.jpg" width="100%" height="25%" alt="me">




        <div style='margin-top:29%'>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-file"></i>Templates</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-folder-plus"></i>New Template</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-chart-line"></i>sous-jacents</a></li>
            <li><a href="creer-sous-jacent"><i class="fas fa-thin fa-filter"></i>New Sous-jacent</a></li>
        </ul> 
      </div>
    
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And there is my simple second html function:

```
{% extends "new_layout.html" %}
{% block content %}

<div>
     <div style="left: 100%; background-color: red;">
          AJUIJOIASAJISOOISAJASIASOAJSOIASJOIASJOIASJOIASJOIAJSOIAJSOIAS
     </div>
     creation sous-jacents
     <form action="creer-sous-jacent", method="post">
          <div>
               libellé
               <input type="text" id="libelle" name="libelle"    required="required"> 
          </div>

          <div>
               Ticker
               <input type="text" id=""ticker name="ticker" required="required">
          </div>
          <div>
               <p><input type="submit" value="submit"></p>
             </div>
     </form>


</div>



{% endblock %}
```

I don't have any problem when i use my old template. I tried to put on the right the content, to put new text but nothing works. I removed all the style in my header but it doesn't work.

If someone has the solution.

Thanks for your reading

Comment: "my html disappears" - what does that mean? Is the markup no longer rendered? Is there any other bug happening? Is this a HTML problem, or a CSS problem?  Also, that code from your "second html function" looks like Twig - is this the case? Are you using any templating engine?

Comment: hello, my code is not displayed. My second function is just  a html function  with a form inside (i don't know twig)

Comment: Please share more details. Is it completely **not** displayed (as in: no markup is rendered after all)? Then what have you tried to resolve this? Is there any error given in your server's log?

Comment: I'm guessing from your top tags that it is a Django template? It's definitely not just html & css